# How to read the data from multiple subscriptions at one go

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

I am looking for help to read the data from 100+ subscriptions at one go. I have a requirement to create a dashboard which can read the data from all the subscriptions at one go and show us the trend in graphical format.

For ex - CPU utilization of VMs.

Can we read the CPU utilization from all the VMs across all the subscriptions and put the highest one in the graph, so that it would be easy for the monitoring team to monitor the platform. It is always easier to see the data in the dashboard rather than going through 1000 emails on daily basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a metrics step to query many resources at once, if you need true metrics.
but there isn't generally a "top x metric value across N subs" functionality of metrics (yet), you are querying a specific metric for specific resources.  you could use workbooks to find the resources in a sub, and use those resources in a metrics step.

Most of these things are limited though, i know metrics is limited to 200 resources a a time.

If you were using something like log analytics, and had all the VMs emitting metrics to the same workspace, then you could do this as a single log analytics query, though.